# How can i make 100 concurrent request to a wcf service from my client

Tags: wcf, console-application

I have a WCF service which is getting down quiet frequently.I have been asked to develop a load test tool for the same by making 100 concurrent requests to the service using chanelfactory.I know how to 1 make request from a client ,but how can i make 100 requests from the same client.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Take a look at parallel programming with .net, or use a commercial tool like LoadComplete.